# Adding M values to point feature attribute table in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, lines-to-points

I want to create a point feature with XYZ and M values. The points are 10m spaced points located on a line. I need this to create cross sections in Grapher. My problem is I cannot seem to get the M values by "add geometry attributes" tool. I first created points along a line(every 10m). Then I made vertices along the line and converted the vertices to points, but the distance along the line just does not get carried over.

ArcMap 10.4.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit and add m values. See [Editing a vertex's m-value or z-value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/editing-a-vertex-s-m-value-or-z-value.htm):

> Vertices can store additional attributes besides x,y locations. The
>   attributes include m-values and z-values, which are often used to
>   store information about route measures and elevation. These attributes
>   are added and modified using the Edit Sketch Properties window. You
>   can open the window by selecting a feature with the Edit tool,
>   double-clicking it, then clicking the Sketch Properties button on the
>   Editor toolbar

Also note that:

> To add m- or z-values to a vertex, you must have specified that the
>   feature class be able to store them when you created the feature
>   class. If you did not set this property, you need to create a new
>   feature class and import the existing features into it.

And then execute Feature Vertices to Points to convert the line vertices to Points.

Comment: Thank you, I did do vertices to Points, but the M value did not seem to come through. Possibly my problem is that the line never had M values. I will also check the environmental settings. I solved it by creating a new point feature at the start of each line and then used the "Near" tool to get the distance from the start of line to each point on the line. It was rather cumbersome because I had to split the lines into separate features, because they are close to each other.